# Is there a good package for solving the Einstein field equations given a metric tensor?

Tags: packages, tensors

I have a very simple metric tensor. I've built a notebook to calculate the EFE solutions based on this metric. Does anyone know of a good package in the Mathematica library that takes a metric tensor and solves the EFE equations so I can check my work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [xAct](http://www.xact.es) package is what I have used for some time for things like this.  It is probably overkill for what you need, and there is a *steep* learning curve, but it will definitely do what you need.

Specifically, if your metric is specified as functions of some set of coordinates, then you will want to looking into the `xCoba` subpackage, which does tensor calculations in **co**ordinate **ba**ses.

Comment: Also, there are a few users on this stack who use this package (including the package's creator), so you can try asking new questions here as you learn the package.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Do you know of a simple example where they put the standard FLRW metric tensor in one side and get the EFE solutions out the other side? (Obviously a(t) would have to be specified as a function of time).

Comment: There are some simple curvature calculations for metrics like FRW, Schwarzschild, etc. in Section 3.6 of the file `xCobaDoc.nb`, available [here.](http://www.xact.es/xCoba/index.html)

Comment: @Micael Seifert - Do you have a problem with George Lemaître?

Comment: @TheShepard:  I'm sure he was a perfectly nice guy, I just didn't learn the acronym that way.

Comment: I don't get it. Where are the solutions to the EFEs?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you wanted.  The package outpus the components of various curvature tensors as expressions in terms of the derivatives metric components.  You still need to feed these differential equations into a basic Mathematica function like `DSolve` or `NDSolve` if you want to know what the metric components are.